# Ability to control lock screen of iPhone running iOS 7 with bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: iphone, ipad, keyboard, bluetooth, ios

On my iPhone with iOS 6, I often use the Amazon bluetooth keyboard to use my iPhone, including turning it on (home button on keyboard) and unlocking (escape button instead of swiping to unlock). But (and I don't remember how this was on iOS 6) with my iPad on iOS 7, the iPad won't respond to the keyboard when the screen is off (can't access lock screen) and the "escape" button doesn't reveal the home screen. (Search button doesn't activate spotlight either, it does on my iPhone with iOS 6, but that's a side issue.)

So would it work on the iPhone? Is this just an iPad problem? Would Apple or Amazon fix this in the future?

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded the iPhone. And yes, the bluetooth keyboard still works to unlock the phone (just not iPad), and unlike in iOS 6 it jumps straight past the "slide to unlock" to the passcode screen.

Interestingly, though, if I show the slide to unlock screen, "esc" no longer swipes it to the passcode screen.

Spotlight/search button on keyboard is, by the way, useless now also on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

For iPhone 6, the <kbd>fn</kbd> button will get you to the passcode screen and then arrow around to the number you need. Then press up down arrow to enter that number. This is with Voice Over.